# how to Call REST-API with post method in CURL from laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, php-curl

I am using laravel 5.6.I want to call **REST-API** with **post** method. where URL Parameter  is **JSON format**. I simply called that API in **Postman** .where it is working. but when i try to call this **Laravel Controller** via **CURL** method then getting 
error

```
Array to string conversion
```

JSON Parameter is

```
{"DebtorID":"00000000080000000002","InitiatedDate":"2018-04- 
 20","OrderNo":"1234","SOReference":"Test order",  
 "Lines":[{"PartNo":"1170","QuantityOrdered":5}, 
          {"CommentLine":"true","CommentText":"This is a comment line"},
          {"InventoryID":"000000000K00000000BV","QuantityOrdered":2,  
           "DiscountedPrice":15.67,
            "CustomFieldValues":[
              {SettingID":"1ae102b94dc54dfc8a45",
                "Contents":"Fragile - do not drop"
                   }
                ]
            }
          ],
           "Payments":[{"PaymentRef":"S454873-J5","AmountPaid":50.00}]
        }
}
```

My Laravel code is

```
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL =>$request->url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request->data,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            // Set here requred headers
            "accept: */*",
            "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
            "content-type: application/json",
            "Accept: application/json",
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

This is Sample Image that being call from Postman. when i call this API directly then it is returning  200. 
[image]

but when i try this from laravel then getting  error . please check this image.
[image]

I try to use **postman Generate code Snippets**  that images is below
[image]

Comment: when i add    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data), then  getting  Null from response.

Answer (score 0):

Just use content type to check the response format, so that you can able to print it in the right format.

```
 $contentType = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    echo $contentType;
    echo "<br/>";
  curl_close ($curl);
    echo "<pre>";
```

Comment: but i am not getting anything. when it gone success then it return 201 status code. not 200.

Comment: just use print_r() to display the final response

Comment: i used print_r and getting in response  1. why ? dont know.

Comment: Dear  Ahil Murugesan . i used your  solution but not getting any thing.

Comment: **postman Generate code Snippets** code returning  result on postman but not in laravel.